# Count the number of elements within a set of ranges

Tags: python, list, count

I am facing trouble on writing a function that takes 2 arguments (values, dividers) as a list and returns the number of elements in each range (determined by numbers in dividers) as one list. Elements that are equal to one of the dividers should be counted in the bin below.

I used if and elif to sort the numbers, which is sort of giving me the right idea. However, I am struggling on how to apply the fact 'number of bins = number of dividers + 1'

```
def histogram(values, dividers):
    count1 = 0
    count2 = 0
    count3 = 0
    index = 0
    for index in range(len(values)):
        if values[index] <= min(dividers):
           count1 = count1 + 1
        elif min(dividers) < values[index] <= min(dividers):
           count2 = count2 + 1
        elif values[index] > max(dividers):
           count3 = count3 + 1
        index = index + 1 
    print("Number of elements in each bin is ", [count1, count2, count3])
```

When I run the argument ([1,...,10], [2,5,7]) for instance, the answer should be [2,3,2,3] because the number of elements in range below 2, 2~5 (not including 5), 5~7 (not including 7) and above 7 is 2,3,2,3 respectively. However at the moment, I am getting the output [2,5,3].

P.S. My aim is writing the function without using numpy.histogram or any matplotlib related stuff

Comment: shouldn't the first item in the results be 1? number of elements below 2, not including 2? And shouldn't the last item be 4 (7,8,9,10)?

Comment: `diviiders` argument will always be three items?

Comment: You should always have `len(dividers)+1` bins. You have *hard coded* three bins. If you expect arbitrary length arguments  for `dividers` you need to figure out how to *dynamically* make the comparisons based on the length of `dividers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the most efficient implementation, but it does not assume that `values` is sorted (only that dividers is):

```
def histogram(values, dividers):
    bins = [0]*(len(dividers)+1)
    extended_dividers = [-float('inf')]+dividers+[float('inf')]
    for idx, divider in enumerate(extended_dividers[:-1]):
        bins[idx] = len([v for v in values if divider<v<=extended_dividers[idx+1]])
    return bins
```

Also, shouldn't the output in your example be 1,2,3,4?

Comment: `Elements that are equal to one of the dividers should be counted in the bin below.`